# Flask context missing in 404 errorhandler

Tags: python, flask

I have the following structure for my flask application. When an invalid url comes in a 404 error is called, but my 404.html requires data from the context_processor but in the abort 404 the blueprint is None so context_processor is never called and 404.html is missing data.

How can I approach this differently?

#### **init**.py

```
def create_app(settings_overide=None):
    app = factory.create_app(__name__, __path__, settings_overide)
    if not app.debug:
        app.errorhandler(404)(page_not_found)

    return app

def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

#### processors.py

```
@blueprint.context_processor
def load_global_data():
    return get_data()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a route is not found, no blueprint is set yet (because setting a blueprint requires a route to be determined first). As such a 404 error handler can't count on a blueprint to have been determined.

You'd have to execute the `get_data()` call manually. Test if a specific global has been set, then execute the `get_data()` function if not before rendering your 404 template.